# what (local) server to use for ruby dev: mac os x or linux

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, osx-server

At the office, we have 2 MBPs with Mac OS X & 1 laptop with Ubuntu. We're about to buy a server for local storage & testing, but we're debating on it's operating system.

We're developing in RoR, use the server for local testing & then use Heroku as production site. Current tradeoff: Mac Pro Server (waiting for the new august edition) vs a Linux (distro undecided) machine.

Can someone give advice? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest I always want my test/dev boxes to be the same architecture and software stack as production.

Comment: That's not very realistic when you deploy on heroku. :-)

Comment: @Denis really? you couldn't find out from your host provider what architecture and software stack (exact versions) they were running? Surprising.

Comment: Not really... [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is running on top of a highly virtualized, custom-tailored stack which lives on AWS. It's realistic to get the versions of the various bits and pieces involved, but there's not a chance in hell to get a similar (let alone identical) architecture on a dev server.

Comment: Thx. We decided to get another heroku instance & set it up as test environment. Working locally, then pushing it up to test heroku & from there to the prod heroku. Good way for staged dev.